# LIKE MYSQL only getting 1 result

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When i run this it only get back 1 result from the databse yet there should be 2. Do you know what the problem is or do you need more information

**EXAMPLE DATABASE**

```
URL             tags

www.google.com  google,search,information,cool,

www.youtube.com google,videos,



    $keywords=$_GET["Keywords"];                         
    $explodeKeywords = explode(" ", $keywords); 
    $currentWord = $explodeKeywords[$arrayKeywordCount];
    $arrayKeywordCount++;
    $URLSQUERY=mysql_query("Select URL 
            FROM tagslinks WHERE tags 
            LIKE '%$currentWord,%';");
    $URLSARRAY = mysql_fetch_array($URLSQUERY);
```

Comment: I need more information. Like example data.

Comment: what is the output you are getting in `$URLSARRAY` ?

Comment: You should consider normalizing your database if possible.

Comment: after the line with `explode` it must be an iteration. `$currentWord` contains only the first element of an array `$explodeKeywords`, that means the first keyword. `$arrayKeywordCount` is not defined, so it has 0 value there (`(int) null`).

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch all the results in a loop, executing `mysql_fetch_array` once, gives only 1 result.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($URLSQUERY); $i++) {
    $URLSARRAY[] = mysql_fetch_array($URLSQUERY);
}
```

Comment: It shows up as 'array' instead of the data i was getting

Comment: You select **1 row* containing **several columns**... its a multi-dimensional array.... `echo $URLSARRAY[0]['tags'];`

Comment: thanks for you help but it now only shows the first letter of my data 'w'

Answer (score 0):

Try this->

```
$keywords=$_GET["Keywords"];                         
    $explodeKeywords = explode(" ", $keywords); 
    $currentWord = $explodeKeywords[$arrayKeywordCount];
    $arrayKeywordCount++;
    $URLSQUERY=mysql_query("Select URL 
            FROM tagslinks WHERE tags 
            LIKE '%$currentWord%'");
 while($res=mysql_fetch_array($URLSQUERY)){
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($res);
}
```